# Kubernetes | Expose HTTPS service

Tags: ssl, tomcat, kubernetes, https

I am a newbie to Kubernetes platform trying to enable HTTPS secure connection of tomcat web app deployed in Kubernetes platform. I am confused on manifest.yml pertaining to deployment, service and ingress controller.

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: tomcat-webapp
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: tomcat-webapp
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: tomcat-webapp
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: tomcat-webapp
          image: registry.central/*****
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          securityContext:
            runAsUser: 13113
            runAsGroup: 602
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          env:
            - name: JAVA_OPTS
              value: "-Xms128M -Xmx256M -XX:MetaspaceSize=128m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m"
            - name: CATALINA_OPTS
              value: "-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/opt/apache-tomcat-8.5.32/webapps/ROOT/tomcat.jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=****"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: tomcat-webapp
  labels:
    app: tomcat-webapp
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
      #nodePort: 30010
      protocol: TCP
      name: http
  selector:
    app: tomcat-webapp
---
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: tomcat-webapp
spec:
  rules:
    - host: "tomcat-webapp.apps.net"
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: tomcat-webapp
              servicePort: 80
  tls:
    - hosts:
        # dont forget to update this url too
        - "tomcat-webapp.apps.net"
```

So do I have to specify port 8443 (Https port) also in deployment (under  ports: - containerPort: 8080) service (like  ports: - port: 80 targetPort: 8080 protocol: TCP name: http) and ingress (under backend:serviceName: tomcat-webapp servicePort: 80) ?

Answer (score 1):

Keep it simple:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: tomcat-webapp
  labels:
    app: tomcat-webapp
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 8080
  selector:
    app: tomcat-webapp
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: tomcat-webapp
spec:
  rules:
    - host: "tomcat-webapp.apps.net"
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: tomcat-webapp
              servicePort: 8080
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - "tomcat-webapp.apps.net"`
```

As far as I understand from your Deployment configuration, your Java application runs on port 8080 and expects https traffic. This will not work with the above mentioned Ingress configuration - your Java application should listen on port 8080 and expect http traffic.

If you really want your Java application to listen for HTTPS, you could configure Ingress the following way:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: tomcat-webapp
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
... # the rest is the same
```

Comment: Ok..Many thanks for your reply .. @David Molnar..If i connect to this service externally to cluster like https://tomcat-webapp.apps.net/ from browser,  do i have to define my targetPort 8443 to port 8443 in my service.?

Comment: I think defining `port: 8443` in your service should be enough.